# Polymer app not loading in other browsers such as Firefox

Tags: polymer

I have created an app using Polymer and it works fine in Chrome which is expected. However when loading the app in Firefox for example, I am presented with a blank page.

I have the relevant imports for polyfills as you can see in my code below. Am I missing something to get it to work in other browsers?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gBWxIdOUuizxFH2S5peQ?p=info

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/my-elements/my-appbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/my-elements/my-content.html">
  </head>

  <body fullbleed vertical layout unresolved>
      <core-header-panel flex>
        <div class="core-header">
          <my-appbar></my-appbar>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <my-content></my-content>
        </div>
      </core-header-panel>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you put the code of your components in a Plunker or similarly accessible site? I've tried to open in Firefox one of my simple Plunkers, http://plnkr.co/edit/YGCfKErYZgFyr2KRJnVv?p=preview and it works on Firefox...

Comment: I've created a Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/gBWxIdOUuizxFH2S5peQ?p=info), it seems to load fine there however when I run it on a server locally then I still get a blank page in Firefox.

Comment: Do you see any errors on the firefox console?

Comment: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create webcomponents.js:6008 and
TypeError: controller is undefined polymer.js:10707